# Calculate corner-positions of rectangle-positions with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, matrix

So I'd like to get the 4 corner-positions of a rectangle with javascript.
*(-->top, bottom, left, right)*

I've already found a function that returns all positions [x, y] of the rectangle (1-characters) from the matrix to array-form.

```
var matrix=[
 '000000000000',
 '000111111000',
 '000111111000',
 '000111111000',
 '000000000000'
]
```

So the result_array of the rectangle positions looks like his:

```
var result_array=[
  [3,1], [4,1], [5,1], [6,1], [7,1], [8,1],
  [3,2], [4,2], [5,2], [6,2], [7,2], [8,2],
  [3,3], [4,3], [5,3], [6,3], [7,3], [8,3]
]

var my_result_should_be: {
      "top_left":[3,1],
      "top_right":[8,1],
      "bottom_left":[3,3],
      "bottom_right":[8,3]
    }
```

But now - how to get the corner positions of the rectangle points (x/y-array) above?

My idea was that all rectangles should have:

- min. 1x biggest y_value,
- min. 1x smallest y_value,
- min. 1x biggest x_value,
- min. 1x smallest x_value

However I'd like to calculate the 4 corner-points (`[1,3], [1,8], [3,3], [3,8]`) from the rectangle-positions even if the rectangle is rotated with an unknown angle like I've symbolized below:

```
var rotated_matrix=[
  '000000000000',
  '011111000000',
  '000111110000',
  '000001111100',
  '000000000000'
]

var result_array= [
  [1,1],[2,1],[3,1],[4,1],[5,1],
  [3,2],[4,2],[5,2],[6,2],[7,2],
  [5,3],[6,3],[7,3],[8,3],[9,3],
]

var my_result_should_be: {
  "top_left":[1,1],
  "top_right":[5,1],
  "bottom_left":[5,3],
  "bottom_right":[9,3]
}
```

So I coded also a function that is able to return the listed points from above (maxX, minX, maxY, minY), but because there could be multiple max/min-points (because e.g. Y-value is the same but x-value not) I'm not sure which points are the right ones. Especially than if the rectangle is rotated...

```js
var result_array=[[1,3], [1,4], [1,5], [1,6], [1,7], [1,8],[2,3], [2,4], [2,5], [2,6], [2,7],[2,8],[3,3], [3,4], [3,5], [3,6], [3,7],[3,8]];

var results = {
   'maxX': result_array.filter(e => e[0] === Math.max(...result_array.map(e => e[0]))),
   'minX': result_array.filter(e => e[0] === Math.min(...result_array.map(e => e[0]))),
   'maxY': result_array.filter(e => e[1] === Math.max(...result_array.map(e => e[1]))),
   'minY': result_array.filter(e => e[1] === Math.min(...result_array.map(e => e[1])))
   }
      
   console.log(results);
```

This is the result of the function above, so like you can see there are several "extreme points" but which of them are the right ones?

```
var extreme points: {
  "maxX":[[3,3],[3,4],[3,5],[3,6],[3,7],[3,8]],
  "minX":[[1,3],[1,4],[1,5],[1,6],[1,7],[1,8]],
  "maxY":[[1,8],[2,8],[3,8]],
  "minY":[[1,3],[2,3],[3,3]]
}
```

I hope somebody has an idea how to solve this problem, however,

Thanks in advance

Comment: same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47356200/calculate-the-corner-positions-of-rectangle-javascript) (deletd now), two accounts?

Comment: Your link is not working @NinaScholz (Page Not Found)

Comment: Sound right, yeah @Taplar. But the `result_array`'s includes all (x/y-coordinates) of my rectangle. So in the result_array there are also my 4 corner-positions (left top, left bottom, right top and right bottom)

Comment: Like I've mentioned above the `...rectangle (1-characters) from...`. The result_array includes all positions of my rectangle. Pleas try to focus on that :) The matrix above is kind of irrelevant @Taplar

Comment: Of course your absolutely right @Taplar but if I had just post an stupid array like my result_array nobody would get my thoughts. So I thought it would a good idea to add some matrix examples to my question. Maybe I was wrong... :/

Comment: @Taplar Edited my question!

Comment: Please just read the question carefully. I've mentioned that the function will return multiple coordinates (inclusive my 4 corners) but I'd like to filter all coordinates to get the right ones. @Taplar